# How to ignore empty database result for the first time and wait for server result in application?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, android-room, android-livedata, offline-caching

My app using room as a database and retrofit as a network calling api.
i am observing database only as a single source of truth. every thing is working fine. But i am not finding solution of one scenario.
Like for the first time when user open app it do following operations

1. fetch data from db
2. fetch data from server

because currently database is empty so it sends empty result to observer which hide progress bar . i want to discard that event and send result to observer when server dump data to database. even server result is empty. so progress bar should always hide once their is confirmation no data exists.

in other words application should always rely on database but if it empty then it should wait until server response and then notify observer.

this is my code

observer

```
viewModel.characters.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            Log.e("status is ", "${it.message} at ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
            when (it.status) {
                Resource.Status.SUCCESS -> {
                    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    if (!it.data.isNullOrEmpty()) adapter.setItems(ArrayList(it.data))
                }
                Resource.Status.ERROR -> {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), it.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                }

                Resource.Status.LOADING ->
                    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        })
```

ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class CharactersViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: CharacterRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    val characters = repository.getCharacters()
}
```

Repository

```
class CharacterRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val remoteDataSource: CharacterRemoteDataSource,
    private val localDataSource: CharacterDao
) {

 

    fun getCharacters() : LiveData<Resource<List<Character>>> {
        return performGetOperation(
            databaseQuery = { localDataSource.getAllCharacters() },
            networkCall = { remoteDataSource.getCharacters() },
            saveCallResult = { localDataSource.insertAll(it.results) }
        )
    }
}
```

Utility function for all api and database handling

```
fun <T, A> performGetOperation(databaseQuery: () -> LiveData<T>,
                               countQuery: () -> Int,
                               networkCall: suspend () -> Resource<A>,
                               saveCallResult: suspend (A) -> Unit): LiveData<Resource<T>> =
    liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {

        emit(Resource.loading())
        val source = databaseQuery().map { Resource.success(it,"database") }.distinctUntilChanged()
            emitSource(source)
        val responseStatus = networkCall()

        if (responseStatus.status == SUCCESS) {
            saveCallResult(responseStatus.data!!)
                

        } else if (responseStatus.status == ERROR) {
            emit(Resource.error(responseStatus.message!!))

        }
    }
```

LocalDataSource

```
@Dao
interface CharacterDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM characters")
    fun getAllCharacters() : LiveData<List<Character>>


    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertAll(characters: List<Character>)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(character: Character)


}
```

DataSource

```
class CharacterRemoteDataSource @Inject constructor(
    private val characterService: CharacterService
): BaseDataSource() {


    suspend fun getCharacters() = getResult { characterService.getAllCharacters() }}
}
```

Base Data Source

```
abstract class BaseDataSource {

    protected suspend fun <T> getResult(call: suspend () -> Response<T>): Resource<T> {
        try {
            Log.e("status is", "started")
            val response = call()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val body = response.body()
                if (body != null) return Resource.success(body,"server")
            }
            return error(" ${response.code()} ${response.message()}")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return error(e.message ?: e.toString())
        }
    }

    private fun <T> error(message: String): Resource<T> {
        Timber.d(message)
        return Resource.error("Network call has failed for a following reason: $message")
    }

}
```

Character Service

```
interface CharacterService {
    @GET("character")
    suspend fun getAllCharacters() : Response<CharacterList>
}
```

Resource

```
data class Resource<out T>(val status: Status, val data: T?, val message: String?) {
    
        enum class Status {
            SUCCESS,
            ERROR,
            LOADING
        }
    
        companion object {
            fun <T> success(data: T,message : String): Resource<T> {
                return Resource(Status.SUCCESS, data, message)
            }
    
            fun <T> error(message: String, data: T? = null): Resource<T> {
                return Resource(Status.ERROR, data, message)
            }
    
            fun <T> loading(data: T? = null): Resource<T> {
                return Resource(Status.LOADING, data, "loading")
            }
        }
    }
```

CharacterList

```
data class CharacterList(
    val info: Info,
    val results: List<Character>
)
```

What is the best way by that i ignore database if it is empty and wait for server response and then notify observer

Comment: did you ever find the answer?

Comment: @DJ.Aduvanchik i have added another count query on the basis of that i am making decision. although its not a good solution but its working. i will let you know when get improved answer.

Comment: thank you. That was helpful, I ended up writing more queries as well